# How to manipulate Json nested attributes in a JavaScript UDF in Snowflake

Tags: javascript, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have to write a JavaScript UDF function in Snowflake that receives a variant as the argument and do some value changes for a few keys. All is good but there's one particular attribute (PROPERTY) that looks like a nested JSON but it has some have escapes (backslash) which add some complexity because one of the requirements is to transform the value for "PROP_3" (nested attribute within PROPERTY). See screen shot.
Any ideas how to approach this request taking the screen shot as the input for the UDF?

[input format for the UDF argument](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qrct9.png)
Thanks

Comment: Instead of a screenshot, can you give us some code we can reproduce? The more code you can share, the more specific answer we can give to your situation. What output are you expecting in this case?

Comment: To be completely accurate about it, the line starting with `PROPERTY:` contains one long string. The backslashes are escaping the control characters to keep it as one string rather than separate key-value pairs. If you want to change it, you're going to have to use string manipulation. You could also parse that string using JSON.parse(), make the change, and then return it to a string using JSON.stringify()

Comment: {
  "KEY": "abc",
  "PROPERTY": "{\"PROP_1\":\"VALUE_1\",\"PROP_2\":\"VALUE_2\",\"PROP_3\":\"VALUE_3\",\"PROP_4\":null}",
  "ATTR_1": 0,
  "ATTR_2": "customer"
}

Comment: Above the format for the input parameter. The output should be in the same format as the input BUT some values should be transformed like this: from VALUE_3 to MASKED_VALUE. @FelipeHoffa

Comment: @GregPavlik. You are right with respect to the backslashes. The input comes in this format and I have no option than dealing with it as it is. I was thinking on parsing the PROPERTY attribute value but couldn't make it work yet. Appreciate your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid UDFs when straight SQL approaches are available. There are rare times when procedural code can outperform straight SQL by doing less work, but that's uncommon.

```
create or replace temp table t1 as select 
parse_json($$ {"KEY":"ABCD","PROPERTY":"{\"PROP1\":\"VALUE1\",\"PROP2\":\"VALUE2\",\"PROP3\":\"VALUE3\",\"PROP4\":null}","ATTR_1":0,"ATTR_2":"customer"} $$) as V;

select 
     object_insert(V, 'PROPERTY', object_insert(parse_json(V:PROPERTY), 'PROP3', 'NEW_VALUE', true), true) as JSON
from t1;
```

If you need to convert PROP3 back to a string property, you can create a very simple JavaScript UDF that applies the `JSON.stringify()` method.